# How to type-hint a link between a class attribute and an instance attribute?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have the following code:

```py
class ParentClass():
    """ParentClass code goes here"""

class ParentCategoryClass():
    """Subclasses of this class are supposed to regroup instances of one or several ParentClass subclasses"""
    elements:dict[str, type[ParentClass]] #This lists the ParentClass subclasses that the category is going to hold

    def __init__(self)
        self.content:dict[str,ParentClass] = {} #This will be filled later with instances of the classes in elements
```

I would like to somehow specify that the `content` attribute will specifically have instances of the `ParentClass` subclasses that are in `elements`.

For example, another file could have:

```py
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    """This one is actually going to be instanciated"""

class ChildCategoryClass(ParentCategoryClass):
    """This one is also going to be instanciated"""
    elements: {"child class": ChildClass}
    # The values in the content dictionary of a ChildCategoryClass will always be ChildClass instances. But I'm not redefining the __init__, so I can't specify that (plus it would be redundant with the elements attribute).
```

There could also be several child classes in the `elements` class attribute.

I tried using `TypeVar` with the following code:

```
class ParentClass():
    """ParentClass code goes here"""

ChildClassVar = TypeVar("ChildClassVar", bound=ParentClass)
class ParentCategoryClass(Generic[ChildClassVar]):
    """Subclasses of this class are supposed to regroup instances of one or several ParentClass subclasses"""
    elements:dict[str, type[ChildClassVar]] #This lists the ParentClass subclasses that the category is going to hold

    def __init__(self)
        self.content:dict[str,ChildClassVar] = {} #This will be filled later with instances of classes in elements
```

But the linter complains that it `Expected type arguments for generic class ParentCategoryClass` in all mentions of `ParentCategoryClass` later on (such as typehinting something to be a `ParentCategoryClass` or inheriting from it).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm missing something, but I think you just need to put your `TypeVar` in scope - see below:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class ParentClass:
    """ParentClass code goes here"""

ChildClassVar = TypeVar("ChildClassVar", bound=ParentClass)
class ParentCategoryClass(Generic[ChildClassVar]):
    """Subclasses of this class are supposed to regroup instances of one or several ParentClass subclasses"""
    elements:dict[str, type[ChildClassVar]] #This lists the ParentClass subclasses that the category is going to hold

    def __init__(self):
        self.content: dict[str,ChildClassVar] = {} #This will be filled later with instances of classes in elements
```

You have to use `Generic` to put `TypeVar` in scope for the class it's being used for. There is also a newer syntax that allows you to do this with just square brackets.

Comment: You are right, I forgot the `Generic` in my solution attempt. Is there any changes I should do on the rest of my code though? All further calls to ParentCategoryClass (as a type hint or for subclassing) give `Expected type arguments for generic class ParentCategoryClass`. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah so this is just how generics work - everywhere you then use `ParentCategoryClass` you have to then specify that part of the generic e.g. `ParentCategoryClass[ChildClass]`. If it's inside another class, and you don't know what type to use, you probably need to use the `TypeVar` and pass it via `Generic` again. See how `Stack` is used here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-generic-classes

Comment: Uh that gets difficult... `ParentClass` has a `fields` dictionary class attribute that sometimes needs to hold a `ParentCategoryClass` subclass, so the type hint is `type[other_types|ParentCategoryClass]`. So I need to change that to `type[other_types|ParentCategoryClass[ChildClassVar]]` (and add `Generic[ChildClassVar]` to the ChildClass definition). (Comment not long enough to put full errors here, I put them in the next one.)

Comment: I get a collection of `Type argument for "Generic" must be a type variable` (in the generic of `ParentClass`), `Expected no type arguments for class "ParentClass"` (in the `ParentClass` `__init__` upon defining an set of `ParentClass` object), `Type variable "ChildClassVar" has no meaning in this context` in the type hint of the `fields` class attribute.

Comment: Try Defining a new TypeVar for ParentClass vs ParentCategoryClass with a different name - this sometimes helps avoid clashes. The other errors just stem from that I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The type of a `dict` is parameterized on the types of the keys and the values, not on the values themselves.

What you want to enforce is strictly a dynamic property, namely

```
isinstance(contents[x], elements[x])
```

for all keys `x`. That's something that should be handled with runtime type checking by whatever adds elements to either dictionary.

---

If the contents of `elements` are actually something that's statically determined (and can't be altered at runtime), you could define a `TypeDict` to use for the type of `content`. `elements` would essentially just be the annotations for the typed dict.

```
class ContentType(TypedDict):
    foo: FooSubclass
    bar: BarSubclass


class ParentCategoryClass():
    elements = ContentType.__annotations__

    def __init__(self)
        self.content: ContentType = {}
```

Comment: The `elements` dict is indeed not supposed to be altered at runtime. However, `TypedDict` doesn't do quite what I want: the keys of `content` are not predetermined. The point of my question is that I don't want to redefine `__init__` (and redeclare `content`) in all the subclasses. Also, `elements` varies between subclasses.

Comment: As long as the keys of `content` are at least a *subset* of the keys of `elements`, that's OK. You can use `class ContentType(TypedDict, total=False)` so that instances of `ContentType` can use as few of the keys as necessary.

Comment: Actually they are not. `content` will be expanded with several instances of each class in `elements`.

Comment: Then my assumption that `isinstance(contents[x], elements[x])` is not correct. Are you trying to use the set of values in `elements` as a union type for the value type of `contents`?

Comment: Yes. At runtime, `elements` will be used to give options for what to add into `contents`.

Comment: OK, in that case, I think you would want something like `ContentType = FooSubclass | BarSubclass`, then `elements = dict(zip(keys, ContentType.__args__))`, and `content: dict[str, ContentType]`?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to not redefine `content`. If it can't be done I'll just use `assert` when I'm getting something from the contents and the exact subclass matters.